# php - Convert timestamp retrieved from SQL Server to CET

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm retrieving several fields from an SQL table one of them being (timestamp in UTC format).
 I need to either add 2 Hours to the timestamp in or convert the timestamp CET timezone.

For the purpose of this question, the variable $EventTime contains the timestamp retreived from the SQL database in this **2015-06-16 15:34:27.000**.

I have tried the code below, however I'm sure it's not correct.

```
 while($result_row=odbc_fetch_array($sql_run)){
                $EventTime=$result_row['EventTime'];
                $EventTime2=$EventTime;
                $EventTime2->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/Rome"));

echo $EventTime2->format("F d, Y g:i a")
....
}
```

Comment: This question can easily be answered by a google search. Give it a try. If you get stuck, come back and post the code of what you have tried with a specific question on where you got stuck.

Comment: @Zerp: I've updated the code which I've tested (which I've tried to copy from another article through a google search). I'm sure it's not correct, hence why I've posted it only for someone to help;